# PHPMailer default configuration SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I know how to use SMTP with PHPMailer:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
```

And it works fine. But my question is:

How can I configure PHPMailer to use these settings on default, so that I do not have to specify them each time I want to send mail?

Comment: If it is about wordpress the check -> wordpress\wp-includes\class-phpmailer.php file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a function, and include / use it.

```
function create_phpmailer() {
  $mail             = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
  return $mail;
}
```

And call create_phpmailer() to create a new PHPMailer object.

Or you can derive your own subclass, which sets the parameters:

```
class MyMailer extends PHPMailer {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $this->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $this->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $this->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
    $this->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
  }
}
```

and use new MyMailer().

Comment: Can I not just edit the class.phpmailer.php file? By default it (at least the current version) starts with: `class PHPMailer
{
    public $Version = '5.2.9';
    public $Priority = 3;
    public $CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';
    public $ContentType = 'text/plain';
    public $Encoding = '8bit';
    public $ErrorInfo = '';
    public $From = 'root@localhost';
    public $FromName = 'Root User';` ... so what if I change the value of `$From` to, let's say, `myname@example.com`

Answer (score 2):

> Can I not just edit the class.phpmailer.php file?

It's best not to edit class files themselves because it makes the code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this hook:

```
 /**
     * Fires after PHPMailer is initialized.
     *
     * @since 2.2.0
     *
     * @param PHPMailer &$phpmailer The PHPMailer instance, passed by reference.
     */
    do_action_ref_array( 'phpmailer_init', array( &$phpmailer ) );
```

From the source of the wp_mail function itself to modify the phpmailer class directly.

Comment: The codex page for that is here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init